# React Stripe checkout multiple line items

Tags: reactjs, next.js, stripe-payments

I have a working React app with stripe checkout. But I need to pass multiple items to pay for in the checkout. Right now again it works fine for just one item. But I have an array of objects called "items" that need to be paid in one payment. What the best way to handle this? so if you see in my code it sais description Bounce House A but the items array can have [{description: 'Bounce House A', amount:200,qty:2},{description: 'Bounce House B', amount:250,qty:1}.

This is my current code:

```
const stripe = new Stripe(process.env.STRIPE_SECRET_KEY)

export default async (req, res) => {
  const { id, amount } = req.body

  try {
    const payment = await stripe.paymentIntents.create({
      amount,
      currency: 'USD',
      description: 'Bounce House A',
      payment_method: id,
      confirm: true,
    })
    console.log(payment)

    return res.status(200).json({
      confirm: 'abc123',
    })
  } catch (error) {}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You would have to store these arrays on your end in your database, with one singular "order ID" that you can pass to Stripe's PaymentIntent under `metadata`. That way, you can look up what items were associated with a PaymentIntent with this custom order ID you design.

Stripe's `metadata` can only store string key-value pairs so you cannot store an array there. You might be able to store the array as a string in some consistent format that allows you to deserialize it back into an array but I wouldn't recommend that.

Comment: I was wondering if to just store the paymentID in my database in my order table, incase they need to provide a refund they have that paymentid, which correct me if im wrong might be used for the stripe refund api??? Also how can I at least pass the customer email in the payment api? Metadata as well?

Comment: you pass customer email to the Customers API, by first creating a Customer, then passing that Customer ID on PaymentIntent creation. Metadata is also a parameter supported on PaymentIntents: https://stripe.com/docs/api/payment_intents/create#create_payment_intent-metadata